# Reading Image File in Go v.s. Reading Image File in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, go, python-imaging-library

I have code written in Python which reads an image file using `PIL` library, and converts it to n-dimensional numpy array of `uint8` values:

```
    def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
          (im_width, im_height) = image.size
          return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    image_raw = Image.open(img)
    image = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_raw)
```

Once I try to print out pixel values from `image[0][0][0]` up to `image[9][0][0]`, I get the following output:

```
image[0][0][0] = 51
image[1][0][0] = 51
image[2][0][0] = 47
image[3][0][0] = 40
image[4][0][0] = 38
image[5][0][0] = 48
image[6][0][0] = 65
image[7][0][0] = 81
image[8][0][0] = 94
image[9][0][0] = 89
image[10][0][0] = 84
```

In Go, I am reading an image by calling the `ioutil.ReadFile` function, and converting it to Tensor by calling Tensorflow API for Go like so:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(imagePath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

tensor, err := tf.NewTensor(string(b))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Once I run this Tensor through a `tf.Session` so that I can convert its values to `uint8`, expand its dimensions so it matches the models input and try to print out pixel values from `tensor[0][0][0][0]` up to `tensor[0][9][0][0]` , I get the following output:

```
tensor[0][0][0][0]: 50
tensor[0][1][0][0]: 48
tensor[0][2][0][0]: 45
tensor[0][3][0][0]: 39
tensor[0][4][0][0]: 37
tensor[0][5][0][0]: 47
tensor[0][6][0][0]: 65
tensor[0][7][0][0]: 80
tensor[0][8][0][0]: 95
tensor[0][9][0][0]: 88
```

I figured that when reading Image in python using `PIL` library, it internally decodes an byte array to an image of specific format. In Go I am reading an array of bytes and converting it to Tensor as is. There is no decoding phase.

I cannot change code in Python, which means that I have to find a way to decode array of byes read by `ReadFile` function, same way as `PIL.Image.open` decodes it.

Is there a package in Go which allows me to read an image the same way as PIL does. What would be the best way to approach this type of problem? Possibly find out if `PIL.Image` library wraps a certain C function and create same wrapper function in Go?

Comment: The standard [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image) package's [`image.Decode`](https://golang.org/pkg/image#Decode) will decode an image for you. You need to know what format `PIL` is using to get the same data from the resultant `image.Image`; probably via looping over the bounds and calling `At` or knowing/converting it to a specific `image.Image` implementation and looping over the `Pix` field.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will do that.